# Java: Listener subclass won't change superclass buttons

Tags: java, swing, listener, subclass

my first post after long time lurking.
I'm trying to write a java program to train my calculation skills as Khan academy removed the never-ending mode on sum, subtraction, etc.

I somehow managed to write the skeleton but I got stuck when I had to implement listeners: *if I create a class that implements ActionListener everything works. But when I try to use a sublass that implements ActionListener the code breaks.* **I'd like to figure out why.**

I have 3 classes.

1. Question: generates 2 random int

   ```
   public class Question {
   public int rand1;
   public int rand2;
       public Question (){
       rand1 = (int) (100 +(Math.random()*900)); // to be sure I have at least 3 digits. See AnswerV2.generate()
       rand2 = (int) (100 + (Math.random()*900));
       }
   ```

   }
2. Answersv2: takes the 2 random int
       from Question, sums them, create 3 different answers switching
       digits, adds the right answer and shuffles them.

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import java.util.Collections;

   public class Answersv2 {
       public ArrayList  Answer_list = new ArrayList();
       public int int1; 
       public int int2;
       String uno;

   ```
   public Answersv2 (int a, int b) {
       int1 = a;
       int2 = b;
   }
   public void generate (){
       StringBuilder due = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder tre = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder quattro = new StringBuilder();

       uno = Integer.toString(int1+int2); // create the string version of int1+int2
       ArrayList <Character> first_answer = new ArrayList<Character>(); // create an arraylist of char to store the chars
       for (char c : uno.toCharArray()) {
       first_answer.add(c); 
       }

       Collections.swap(first_answer,first_answer.size()-2,first_answer.size()-1); // switch tens with units
       for (char c : first_answer) {
           due.append(c);
       }
       String dueString = due.toString();

       Collections.swap(first_answer,first_answer.size()-3,first_answer.size()-2); // switchs hundres with tens
       for (char c : first_answer) {
           tre.append(c);
       }
       String treString = tre.toString();

       Collections.swap(first_answer,first_answer.size()-2,first_answer.size()-1); // switch tens with units
       for (char c : first_answer) {
           quattro.append(c);
       }
       String quattroString = quattro.toString();

       add(uno,dueString,treString,quattroString);
   }
   public void add (String one,String two,String three,String four){
       Answer_list.add(one);
       Answer_list.add(two);
       Answer_list.add(three);
       Answer_list.add(four);
       shuffle();
   }
   public void shuffle() {
       Collections.shuffle(Answer_list);

   }

   public void stampa (){ // command code line version to test the program, ignore this
   System.out.println("--------------------------------");
   System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = : ");
   System.out.println("A " + Answer_list.get(0));
   System.out.println("B " + Answer_list.get(1));
   System.out.println("C " + Answer_list.get(2));
   System.out.println("D " + Answer_list.get(3));
   }
   public class CoolButton extends JButton{
       public CoolButton(String answer) {
       setText(answer);
       }
       public boolean checkme() { // method to check if the button pressed was the one with the right answer. I still haven't implemented this properly, ignore this too
       if (getText() == uno) {
       return true;
       } else {
       return false;
       }
   }
   }
   }
   ```

   3 QuizV2: Creates the GUI and starts the program.

Now... I created a StartListener subclass of QuizV2 in order to make the buttons being able to read the 4 answers from the answer object created in the QuizV2's main and use it to 
setText() and to change label text, etc.

Here is the code (Quizv2) with the subclass:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Quizv2{
    public MyLabel label = new MyLabel("Click Start");
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    Answersv2 pinolo;
    Question domanda;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button1;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button2;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button3;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button4;

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Quizv2 quiz = new Quizv2();
    quiz.go();  
}
    public void go () {
    Question domanda = new Question();
    Answersv2 pinolo = new Answersv2(domanda.rand1,domanda.rand2);
    pinolo.generate();


    button1 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(0));
    button1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button2 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(1));
    button2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button3 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(2));
    button3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button4 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(3));
    button4.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SPI trainer - Sum");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    label.setForeground(randomColor);
    panel.add(label);


    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.add(button);
    ActionListener doGreeting = new StartListener();
    button.addActionListener(doGreeting );

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);
    panel.add(button4);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

    }
    }
    class StartListener extends Quizv2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("boo");

            label.setLabelText("The button text changed.");

            }

        }
```

However it seems I'm doing something wrong as it prints 'boo' but it doesn't change the label text. I'd like to avoid to use

```
class StartListener extends Quizv2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (buttony == e.getSource()) {
                           label.setLabelText( domanda.rand1 + " + " + domanda.rand2 + " = : ????");
                       button1.setVisible(true);
                       button2.setVisible(true);
                       button3.setVisible(true);
                       button4.setVisible(true);
                       button.setVisible(false);
                            .....
                            .....
                        else if (buttonx == e.getSource())
                        ....

            }

        }
```

in order to figure out which button was pressed so that the programs knows which block of code execute.
I then tried not to use a subclass and everything worked out. Here is the code (Quizv2)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Quizv2 implements ActionListener{
    public MyLabel label = new MyLabel("Click Start");
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    Answersv2 pinolo;
    Question domanda;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button1;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button2;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button3;
    Answersv2.CoolButton button4;

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Quizv2 quiz = new Quizv2();
    quiz.go();  
}
    public void go () {
    domanda = new Question();
    pinolo = new Answersv2(domanda.rand1,domanda.rand2);
    pinolo.generate();

    button1 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(0));
    button1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button2 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(1));
    button2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button3 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(2));
    button3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button4 = pinolo.new CoolButton(pinolo.Answer_list.get(3));
    button4.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SPI trainer - Sum");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    label.setForeground(randomColor); // Little bit of color
    panel.add(label);


    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    panel.add(button1);
    button1.setVisible(false);
    panel.add(button2);
    button2.setVisible(false);
    panel.add(button3);
    button3.setVisible(false);
    panel.add(button4);
    button4.setVisible(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setLabelText( domanda.rand1 + " + " + domanda.rand2 + " = : ????");
        button1.setVisible(true);
        button2.setVisible(true);
        button3.setVisible(true);
        button4.setVisible(true);
        button.setVisible(false);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant _if I create a class that implements ActionListener everything works. But when I try to use a sublass that implements ActionListener the code breaks_

Comment: There are way too many lines of code here for anyone to want to help. Run a debugger, pinpoint the issue, and then post a simplified question of the issue if you want quicker and more concise answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I suggest you put this program aside for quite awhile.  You are making a lot of basic errors, so I don't see how you got anything to compile.  And your code is a labyrinth which is a sign that the program is way too complex for your abilities at this time.

2) Your post also shows that you need to improve your debugging skills.  You really shouldn't post more than about 20 lines of code when asking a question.  Reducing a problem to around 20 lines of code is an exercise that improves your debugging skills.  90% of the code you posted is irrelevant to your problem.  For instance, your whole Answerv2 class could have been reduced to this:

```
public class Answersv2 { 
    public ArrayList<String> Answer_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public Answersv2 () {
        Answer_list.add("300", "150", "160", "170");
    }
}
```

Do you really think that the way your code calculated those strings is relevant to why clicking on a button fails to  change the text of a label?  In fact, your whole Answerv2 class is irrelevant.

The number of lines of code your program can contain is proportional to your debugging skills.  You cannot write a 500 line program two days after learning java.  And writing Swing programs adds a lot of moving parts, so you need to have a solid grasp of the basics before attempting Swing--like not trying to access a non-static variable inside a static method.

When you are having trouble with some code, like your inheritance problem, start a new program to experiment.   Make the new program as simple as possible:

1) Write a basic Swing program that sets up the relevant swing components...

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

class MyGui {
    protected JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
    protected JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

    public MyGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(300, 100, 500, 300);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        Container cpane = frame.getContentPane();
        cpane.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class SwingProg {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        new MyGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    } }
```

2) Get an actionPerformed() method in the same class to work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyGui implements ActionListener {  //********
    protected JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
    protected JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

    public MyGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(300, 100, 500, 300);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        button.addActionListener(this);  //**********
        panel.add(button);

        Container cpane = frame.getContentPane();
        cpane.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   //**************
        System.out.println("boo");
        label.setText("The button was clicked!");
    }

}

public class SwingProg {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        new MyGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3) Now try inherit from MyGui and put the actionPerformed method in the child class.  Okay, so you can't figure out how to make it work.  Now at least you have a simple example to post.

The problem with your button is: you never specified that the actionPerformed() method in the subclass should be the listener for the button. Here is a solution to your problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyGui {
    protected JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
    protected JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

    public MyGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(300, 100, 500, 300);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        Container cpane = frame.getContentPane();
        cpane.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class StartListener extends MyGui implements ActionListener {
    public StartListener(){
        super();
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boo");
        label.setText("The button text changed.");
    }
}

public class SwingProg {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        new StartListener();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Don't try to solve problems in the middle of a complex program.  Instead, extrapolate the problem out into a new program, and solve the problem in the new program.

Comment: 1+ and wishing I could vote it 100+, especially for the recommendation: `"Don't try to solve problems in the middle of a complex program. Instead, extrapolate the problem out into a new program, and solve the problem in the new program."`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to go through all my messy code, for your advices about how to post, how to debug and everything! Thank you also for solving my problem, I was going mad. Now on I'll build a simpler program to find out what and why my program is not working.

Comment: @user2535658, You're welcome.  By the way, if you look below your post, you should see `share | edit | delete | flag`.  If you click on edit, you can make corrections to your post.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed it. I fixed the typo.